# What is the point of fr units in CSS Grid if the content inside the item can expand it beyond its allotment

Tags: html, css, css-grid

div with item 2 here will expand the row height to be greater than 1fr:

```
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2 what happens to me when i'm too big? It's not fair to others</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
.container > * { outline: 1px solid green;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did assume, wrongly, that it would behave somewhat like 50%, but as it turns out, the fr doesn't really apply if the content has exceeded the width. In that case, the width becomes the content-width and the other item (defined by 1fr) gets what's leftover in space.